# How do I get DeploymentPlanContributor.PublishMessage to show up in output window for SSDT in VS 2012? This was the behavior in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, extensibility, sql-server-data-tools

I'm upgrading a VS 2010 database extension project to VS 2012 SSDT extension project now that extensibility is in SSDT.  I used base.PublishMessage to output messages as my extension was running.  In SSDT, base.PublishMessage is not displaying in the output window.  I was wondering if there are other settings I need to make.  I'm not finding a lot of info out there yet and the online doc and samples are sparse.